# How can I add borders

Tags: listings, framed

Given this, how can I add a border around?

```
\begin{ttfamily}
\begin{lstlisting}
g@g0001:~$ cd Desktop
g@g0001:~/Desktop$ cat script.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo $1 `date`

g@g0001:~/Desktop$ ./script.sh "hello"
hello Wed Dec 19 06:30:49 CET 2012

g@g0001:~/Desktop$ ./script.sh "`ls -la`"
total 244 drwxr-xr-x 2 g g 4096 2012-12-19 06:29
. drwxr-xr-x 34 g g 4096 2012-12-19 06:23
.. -rwxr-xr-x 1 g g 314 2012-11-24 12:06
25332.txt -rw------- 1 g g 1038 2008-01-15 18:59
Makefile -rw-r--r-- 1 g g 227981 2011-09-06 10:37
.pdf -rwxrwxrwx 1 g g 29 2012-12-18 18:16
script.sh Wed Dec 19 06:31:18 CET 2012
\end{ttfamily}
```

I tried `\fbox` but I get an error.

Comment: Since you have some responses for [your other questions](http://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a22878%20is%3aquestion) of which some have valid answers, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://goo.gl/hzFkJ)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers.

Comment: Sorry about that. Once I tried to upvote but I got a message saying I couldn't just do that since my score was too low..

Comment: @g9999 Upvoting is different from accepting. You can't upvote answers or questions until your reputation is less than 15 (it's a mild protection against abuses); accepting will help other users with similar problems in understanding what answer was the most useful to the questioner.

Comment: @g9999 BTW, you can already upvote answers now that your reputation is greater than 15 :)

Comment: I have a solution but it doesnt't work properly. I added the following code: \lstset{framexleftmargin=1mm, frame=shadowbox, rulesepcolor=\color{black}} but unfortunately I always get an error. On the other end if I remove rulesepcolor=\color{black}, it works fine but of course I can't have a black frame. Thanks

Comment: Often, just saying "I get an error" isn't very helpful. What does the error say? The best is usually to create a complete  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that demonstrates the problem. But anyways, to use `\color` you have to load the `color` package, are you doing that?

Comment: No that's probably the problem..I added \usepackage{color} to my preamble and it all goes like clockwork now..thanks a lot

Comment: `\ttfamily` is not supposed to be used as an environment. Don't use font switching commands as environments.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 15):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

```
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88564/how-can-i-add-borders
\documentclass[border=5,preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
frame=single
}
\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
g@g0001:~$ cd Desktop
g@g0001:~/Desktop$ cat script.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo $1 `date`

g@g0001:~/Desktop$ ./script.sh "hello"
hello Wed Dec 19 06:30:49 CET 2012

g@g0001:~/Desktop$ ./script.sh "`ls -la`"
total 244 drwxr-xr-x 2 g g 4096 2012-12-19 06:29
. drwxr-xr-x 34 g g 4096 2012-12-19 06:23
.. -rwxr-xr-x 1 g g 314 2012-11-24 12:06
25332.txt -rw------- 1 g g 1038 2008-01-15 18:59
Makefile -rw-r--r-- 1 g g 227981 2011-09-06 10:37
.pdf -rwxrwxrwx 1 g g 29 2012-12-18 18:16
script.sh Wed Dec 19 06:31:18 CET 2012
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here, the frame was achieved with the `frame` option with value `single`. The default value is `none`. You can choose from other values: `leftline`, `topline`, `bottomline`, `lines`, or `shadowbox`. Also, you don't need to put your listings inside `\begin{ttfamily}...\end{ttfamily}` as this can be set by the option `basicstyle`. The font styles can be achieved through options among others `basicstyle`, `keywordstyle`, `numberstyle`, `identifierstyle`, `commentstyle`, etc. You can set these and more.

Consult the `listings` manual (specifically Section 4.6 and 4.11) by clicking on this [link](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) or by entering `texdoc listings` in your terminal. For a full set of frame options, see Section 4.11.

Answer (score 3):

`listings` option `frame` is probably the easiest way to frame code, but there also exist other packages which provide more flexible and sophisticated environments for this purpose. `tcolorbox` is one of them. It includes an specific libraries for code listings processed with `listings` or `minted`.

Following code shows the default result and another one with some customization.

```
\documentclass[multi=tcblisting, border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
%\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tcblisting}{listing only}
g@g0001:~$ cd Desktop
g@g0001:~/Desktop$ cat script.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo $1 `date`

g@g0001:~/Desktop$ ./script.sh "hello"
hello Wed Dec 19 06:30:49 CET 2012

g@g0001:~/Desktop$ ./script.sh "`ls -la`"
total 244 drwxr-xr-x 2 g g 4096 2012-12-19 06:29
. drwxr-xr-x 34 g g 4096 2012-12-19 06:23
.. -rwxr-xr-x 1 g g 314 2012-11-24 12:06
25332.txt -rw------- 1 g g 1038 2008-01-15 18:59
Makefile -rw-r--r-- 1 g g 227981 2011-09-06 10:37
.pdf -rwxrwxrwx 1 g g 29 2012-12-18 18:16
script.sh Wed Dec 19 06:31:18 CET 2012
\end{tcblisting}

\begin{tcblisting}{listing only, title=Framed listing with title, colback=blue!20, colframe=blue!70!black, sharp corners}
g@g0001:~$ cd Desktop
g@g0001:~/Desktop$ cat script.sh

#!/bin/bash
echo $1 `date`

g@g0001:~/Desktop$ ./script.sh "hello"
hello Wed Dec 19 06:30:49 CET 2012

g@g0001:~/Desktop$ ./script.sh "`ls -la`"
total 244 drwxr-xr-x 2 g g 4096 2012-12-19 06:29
. drwxr-xr-x 34 g g 4096 2012-12-19 06:23
.. -rwxr-xr-x 1 g g 314 2012-11-24 12:06
25332.txt -rw------- 1 g g 1038 2008-01-15 18:59
Makefile -rw-r--r-- 1 g g 227981 2011-09-06 10:37
.pdf -rwxrwxrwx 1 g g 29 2012-12-18 18:16
script.sh Wed Dec 19 06:31:18 CET 2012
\end{tcblisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `frame` for your listing:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[frame=single]
...
\end{lstlisting}
```

Or if you don't want to add `frame=single` to every `lstlisting` environment, you can define and set a default style:

```
\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{frame=single}    
\lstset{style=mystyle}
```

For different border types, look at the Frames section of the [documentation](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/listings/listings.pdf).